# What affect more the battery time: mA or V?

Tags: voltage, amperage

I will create a small circuit with a battery and vibration motor. I will use a 3V coin battery with 100 mAh.

So, I can use a motor:

1. With 3V and 75mA
2. With 3V and 150mA
3. With 1.5V and 75mA
4. With 1.5V and 150mA

What will drain less energy of the battery: **3 < 4 <= 1 < 2**? (3 drain less than 4 and drain less or equal to 1 and drain less than 2). Is it correct?

Comment: You just multiply together to get mW and the lower the value the less the drain. But you mention a 3V coin battery and then show options involving 1.5V, are you going to use a 1.5V cell instead or drop the voltage some other way? For coin cells you also need to check the peak discharge current, it might be worth mentioning exactly what kind of batteries you have in mind.

Comment: I will use the best thing to transform the voltage from 3V to 1.5V and I don't know if it affect the battery. But, lets be theoretical and not use the real world :)

Comment: First: Chhose battery to suit motor used.
Minimum voltage from battery must be adequate for your application. Maximum voltage from battery must not be excessive for your application. THEN: run time for a given battery voltage is related to motor mA and battery mAh. Run time in hours ~~~= mAh/mA.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most convenient way to determine power use will be to simply multiply the voltage by the current to give power, so from lowest to highest (ignoring the equal values) we have:

- 1.5V x 75mA = 112.5mW
- 3V x 75mA = 225mW
- 1.5V x 150mA = 225mW
- 3V x 150mA = 450mW

However in practice if you want to go from 3V down to 1.5V you'll need a step-down converter, even a very efficient one will still add say 5% to the power consumed because of the quiescent current and converter efficiency so then that will change the order a little for one of the 1.5V options:

- 1.5V x 75mA x 1.05 = 118mW
- 3V x 75mA = 225mW
- 1.5V x 150mA x 1.05 = 236mW
- 3V x 150mA = 450mW

You should also check the datasheet for the coin cells you're using to check the maximum recommended discharge current. For example the table at the following site suggests that for a CR2032 even for pulsed operation 25mA is the maximum along with 5mA for continuous current.

http://www.eemb.com/Li-MnO2_battery.html

Answer (score 1):

It's sometimes does not sound just multiplying voltage into current. 
Due to the maximum power transfer function of the battery. It also depends on the internal 
chemistry of the battery (ex - solar panel is modeled as a current source).

So your it's always better to get rated battery current so it's on it's maximum operating 
point(sine the load is near the max output of the battery). You have to find the datasheet of the battery and model this battery in a simulator and calculate the feasibility.

EDIT: some applications which sink large transient currents (ex -mobil phone receive a SMS or an incoming call) ,you could use capacitor bank for that. That way you still take more current than the actually battery willingly happy to provide. Study this case study: 
http://www.makestuff.eu/wordpress/powering-a-mobile-phone-with-no-battery/